# Angular angular-auth-oidc-client issue wanted to read authzData but nothing was found

Tags: angular, token, identityserver4, openid-connect

I am trying to connect from my angular app to Identity server but I am getting "wanted to read clientId_authzData but nothing was found"

I am using angular11 and "angular-auth-oidc-client": "^11.5.1",

I followed the steps from below
https://github.com/damienbod/angular-auth-oidc-client/blob/main/docs/quickstart.md

component.hml file

---

```
<button (click)="login()">Login</button>
<button (click)="callapi()">Call API</button>
<button (click)="logout()">Logout</button>
```

component.ts file

---

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    
    this.oidcSecurityService.checkAuth().subscribe((auth) => console.log('is authenticated', auth));
}
login() {
    this.oidcSecurityService.authorize();
    
    this.oidcSecurityService.userData$.subscribe((usr) => {
      console.log("User -->", usr);
    })

    console.log("Token --> " + this.oidcSecurityService.getIdToken());
  }

  callapi(){

  }

  logout() {
    this.oidcSecurityService.logoff();
  }
```

app.Module.ts

---

```
export function configureAuth(oidcConfigService: OidcConfigService) {
  return () =>
    oidcConfigService.withConfig({
      stsServer: 'https://localhost:5001',
      redirectUrl: window.location.origin,
      postLogoutRedirectUri: window.location.origin,
      clientId: 'clientangular',
      scope: 'openid profile api1 roles offline_access',
      responseType: 'code',
      //silentRenew: false,
      //silentRenewUrl: `${window.location.origin}/silent-renew.html`,
      logLevel: LogLevel.Debug,
    });
}
```

Identity server client setup

---

```
new Client
            {
                ClientId = "clientangular",
                ClientName = "Unity Angular Client",
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code, 
                RequireClientSecret = false,
                AllowedScopes = new List<string>
                {
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                    "api1",
                    "roles"
                },

                
                RedirectUris = new List<string> {"http://localhost:4200"},
                PostLogoutRedirectUris = new List<string> {"http://localhost:4200"},
                AllowedCorsOrigins = new List<string> { "http://localhost:4200"},
                
                RequireConsent= false,
                RequirePkce = true,
                //AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken = true,
                AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
                AllowOfflineAccess = true
            }
```

1. While clicking the login button it is redirecting to the identity server
2. After enter the user id and password its is redirect back to the angular page
3. **I can see the authenticated value as false and can't get token also**

I have attached the console log. Kindly help me on this

[image: Console Log]

Comment: I am facing the same issue with Ionic 4, Angular 10, Keycloak OIDC Server 11.0.3 and angular-auth-oidc-client 11.6.4